# PHP validation not running at specific position

Tags: php, validation

```
    <?php
include 'header.inc.php ';
?>

<?php 
$firstNameError = '';
$emailError='';
$lastNameError='';
$passwordError1='';
$passwordError2='';
?>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $firstName = ($_POST["firstname"]);
  if (empty($firstName))
  {
      $firstNameError = "<span style='color: red';> Name is required </span>";
      //echo $nameError;
  }
  //else
  //{
     // echo "success!";
  //}
  $lastName = ($_POST["lastname"]);
  if (empty($lastName))
  {
      $lastNameError = "<span style='color: red';> Last Name is required </span>";
      //echo $nameError;
  }
    $email = ($_POST["email"]);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
  {
      $emailError = "<span style='color: red';> Proper Email account is required </span>";
      //echo $nameError;
  }
  $password1=($_POST["password1"]);
  if(mb_strlen($password1) <8 || preg_match('/[^0-9A-Za-z]/', $password1)) // [^] sign means complement of all those number and alpha, so if password match with something not alpha or number enter the if condition
    {
          $passwordError1= "<span style='color: red';> ONLY CAN USE ALPHABETS OR NUMBERS AND MINIMUM LENGTH Of 8 CHARACTERS </span>";
    }
  $password2=($_POST["password2"]);
  if ($password2 !== $password1)
  {
      $passwordError2="<span style='color: red';> Mismatching passwords! </span>";
  }
}

?>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/newcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="register.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="pull-left square">
                <p> Account </p>
                <p> Login </p>
                <p> Register </p>
                <p> Recover Password </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="">
                  <h3> Register Account</h3>
                  <p> If you already have an account with us, please login at the login page </p>
                  <form action= "register.php" method="post" id="test" onsubmit="return checks()" > 
                      <label>First name:</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="firstname" title="enter your name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["firstname"]) ? $_POST["firstname"] : ''; ?>"> <?php  echo $firstNameError ?>
                      <br>
                      <label>Last Name:</label>  <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" > <?php  echo $lastNameError ?>
                      <br>
                      <label>Email:</label>   <input name="email" id="email" type="text" > <?php  echo $emailError ?>
                      <br>
                      <label>Password:</label>   <input type="password" name="password1"  id="pass1"  title="8 characters minimum"> <?php  echo $passwordError1 ?>
                      <br>
                      <label>Password Confirm:</label> <input type="password" name="password2"  id="pass2"  title="passwords dont match"><?php  echo $passwordError2 ?>
                      <br>
                      <label class="align">
                          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" required> Remember me
                      </label>
                      <br>
                      <input class="align" id="submit" name = "submit" type="submit" value="submit">
                  </form>
              </div>
        </div>    
    </div>

</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<!--<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="register.js"></script>-->



<?php
include 'footer.inc.php ';
?>
```

The code appended here runs fine as it is but when i try to move the PHP validation code, mainly from is_set($_post[submit]) and onwards to the bottom of the HTML document at the area just above where the footer php file is included the validation doesnt run anymore. Please expain to me why this is so?

Comment: Because in second case you define `$passwordError2` (and other validation errors) __after__ you use them.

Comment: The page is read from top to bottom. if you move the validation part below the html form, the validation will occure after the display of the page.

Comment: @cid but i do want the validation to take place only after the submit button is pressed, so it shouldnt matter whr the validation code is?

Comment: @u_mulder arent they already defined at the top <?php 
$firstNameError = '';
$emailError='';
$lastNameError='';
$passwordError1='';
$passwordError2='';
?>

Comment: @YeoBryan when you press submit, the page it reloaded with the content of `POST`

Comment: So they're defined as empty. You set values __after__ you output. So, you output __empty values__.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what you mean but. .. In your case i would stack all errors together and if any error stop else do what you have to do:

```
$erors='';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $firstName = ($_POST["firstname"]);
    if (empty($firstName)){
      $erors .= "<span style='color: red';> Name is required </span>";
    }

    $lastName = ($_POST["lastname"]);
    if (empty($lastName)){
        $erors . = "<span style='color: red';> Last Name is required </span>";
    }

    $email = ($_POST["email"]);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $erors . = "<span style='color: red';> Proper Email account is required </span>";
    }

    $password1=($_POST["password1"]);
    if(mb_strlen($password1) <8 || preg_match('/[^0-9A-Za-z]/', $password1)){
        $erors .= "<span style='color: red';> ONLY CAN USE ALPHABETS OR NUMBERS AND MINIMUM LENGTH Of 8 CHARACTERS </span>";
    }

    $password2=($_POST["password2"]);
    if ($password2 !== $password1){
        $erors .="<span style='color: red';> Mismatching passwords! </span>";
    }

    if($erors){
        echo $erors;
    } else{
        //do stuff
    }
}
```